# No device is showing up in network and host connection in virtual machine on vmwareworkstation

Tags: networking, windows-10, vmware-workstation

I am running windows 10 and installed vmware workstation 11.
while installing Centos 7 on VMware workstation, I am not getting any device in Network and host section. 
My host machine is connected to internet via wifi and working fine. Please help me to connect my VM to the internet.

Comment: Did you allow a Network Device for your VM? What setting is it under VMWare? NAT? Bridged? Local only? And also is it marked as "Connected" ?

Comment: Please share control panel -> network connection see if you have vmnet0

Comment: Hi Darius, i have tried with NAT and Bridged.

Comment: @mussdroid  yes i can see two options there- vmware network adaptor Vmnet1 and Vmnet8, and both are enabled.

Comment: you need to have Vmnet0 , i will post the answer soon

Comment: please share virtual machine setting screenshot

Comment: go to VMware Player installation directory , do you see network.cab file there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bridged network issue and you need have Vmnet0 to add it ,  follow the video http://bit.ly/2aepgjU

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot mussdroid. it worked.
However i was trying to create VM on workstation 11 where it didnt work. For a change i tried on vmware player and it worked.

Comment: you are welcome , i am happy that you have solved the issue